# How to define the annotation for action with image result?

Tags: java, struts2, annotations

I was ok to define it in *struts.xml* config.

```
<action name="getImage" class="my.action.GetImageAction">
      <result name="success" type="stream">  
          <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>  
          <param name="inputName">imageStream</param>  
          <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>  
      </result>  
</action>
```

And I am now trying to define it by annotation on the class with *namesapce*, *result path*, and I have no idea how to do it. Please help :)

I have tried

```
@Namespace("/my/namespace")
@ResultPath("/")
@Result(name = "success", type = "imageResult")
public class GetImageAction extends ActionSupport {
.....
@Override
@Action("/getImage")
public String execute() throws Exception {
.....
```

And I got an error

```
HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action
```

Comment: +1 for existing answer. Are you aware that the S2 docs contain information regarding the use of annotations? Using an arbitrary result type that doesn't match up with anything in S2, or even your own XML configuration, seems like an unusual approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says the results have to be defined at the Action.
The definition would look like this

```
@Action(value = "getImage", results = { @Result(
        name = "success", 
        type = "stream", 
        params = {"contentType", "application/pdf" }) })
```

In the example you see the type too and how to define the contentType.

And the stream will be returned by the "getFileInputStream"-method:

```
public InputStream getFileInputStream() {

            return fileInputStream;
    }
```

the "getContentDisposition"-Method has to be available in the Action-class

```
public String getContentDisposition() {
    return "attachment; filename=" + getFilename() + ".pdf";
}
```